# How not to "write" some value of a list?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I have created a big script with a lot of help from this forum.

But it is very slow. The main problem is coming from the fact that I wrote everything on my spreadsheet, and then retrieve some value and clean all the boxes with a .setValue("") or a .clearContent().

I guess that there is an easy way not to write the values, instead of write then clean...

here is my code :

```
function PLANNING() {
  var PLsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PLANNING_DATA");
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");
  var COsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1_REALISATION PROJETS");
  

////////////////////// PLANNING 2D

//entêtes des plannings
  PLsheet.getRange('M1:T1').setValues([['2D TASK','2D PROJECT', '2D RESPONSIBLE', "START DATE", 'END DATE', 'PROGRESS', 'FINISH?', 'PHASE']]);
  var values = COsheet.getRange('A2:AA' + COsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var res = values.flatMap(valueRange =>
  {

  var DUR = valueRange[7] instanceof Date ? new Date(valueRange[7].getTime() - (100 * 86400000)) : valueRange[7];
  var BAT = valueRange[7] instanceof Date ? new Date(valueRange[7].getTime() - (15 * 86400000)) : valueRange[7];

  return [
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[1], valueRange[6], DUR, valueRange[7], valueRange[8], valueRange[2], 'durée projet'],
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[1], valueRange[6], BAT, BAT, 'BK', valueRange[2], 'date BAT'],
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[1], valueRange[6], valueRange[7], valueRange[7], 'BK', valueRange[2], 'date BAP'],
    ];
  });
  //Logger.log(res)
  PLsheet.getRange(2, 13, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);



  //remplir les cases projets vides :
  var project2D = PLsheet.getRange(2,14,PLsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  // skip the first row of values assuming it alread has a value
  
  for( let i=1; i<project2D.length; i++ ) {
  if( project2D[i][0] === "" ) project2D[i][0] = project2D[i-1][0];
  }
  PLsheet.getRange(2,14, project2D.length, 1 ).setValues(project2D);
  
  //remplir les cases FINISH vides :
  var finish2D = PLsheet.getRange(2,19,PLsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  // skip the first row of values assuming it alread has a value
  
  for( let i=1; i<finish2D.length; i++ ) {
  if( finish2D[i][0] === "" ) finish2D[i][0] = finish2D[i-1][0];
  }
  PLsheet.getRange(2,19, finish2D.length, 1 ).setValues(finish2D);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)


//////////////////////cleaning

  //clean empty task
  var d2cleanervalues = PLsheet.getRange(2, 15, PLsheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < d2cleanervalues.length; i++) {
    if (d2cleanervalues[i][0] === "") {
      PLsheet.getRange(2 + i, 16, 1, 1).setValue("");
      PLsheet.getRange(2 + i, 17, 1, 1).setValue("");

    }
  }
  //clean finish "TRUE" (Vrai)
  var d2cleanervalues = PLsheet.getRange(2, 17, PLsheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < d2cleanervalues.length; i++) {
    if (d2cleanervalues[i][0] === true) {
      PLsheet.getRange(2 + i, 16, 1, 1).setValue("");
      PLsheet.getRange(2 + i, 17, 1, 1).setValue("");

    }
  }



}
```

Comment: Please modify your [mcve] to focus in directly on your question and nothing else

Comment: `//clean empty task` and `//clean finish "TRUE"` - for every row of data you have four  (4) `setValue` - that slows things down. 1) These two sections look as they could be combined into a single routine combining a single `getValues()` (covering columns O,P and Q), a single `for` statement, and a single `IF/else IF` (evaluating Column O and Column Q) and assigning the relevant row values to a "temporaryArray", and lastly a single `setValues()` using the value of the "temporaryArray". I'd be surprised if that didn't have a substantial effect on the overall run time.

Comment: Hi, I have try to use your suggestion to create an answer to my proble ! @Tedinoz and @ Cooper, if you have one minute to check the answer to my own question, I will be able to correct it to give an answer to my question ! thanks !

Comment: Please supply a complete sample of data for the various sheets as well as an example of the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tedinoz, I made a big edit and add as much info as I can, thank you very much for your time !

Comment: Your `d2cleanervalues` references Column 15 ("O") and Column 17 ("P") in sheet "PLANNING_DATA". However your spreadsheet doesn't contain any data in Columns "O" or "Q" on "PLANNING_DATA". Please ensure that your spreadsheet data that aligns with the code in your question.

Comment: I think I should create a new question, because I have been working on 2 different planning created from the same "base" code, and in the question the code refer to the second planning (wrote on planning data from column 'M to T'). But in my own answer, the code refer to the first planning, (wrote on planning data from column 'A to I'). Can you focus on my "answer" rather then my "question", or do you think it's better if I create a new "topic" ? Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 0):

The following answer appears to solve the OP's question.

Notes:

- The column value that equates to `TYPE` isn't know, so not value was selected.
- I used the nested array `res` developed by the OP.

  - There are 6 arrays for each project row.
  - so the increment in the counter variable must be `i += 6` instead of the usual `i++`
  - `rowCounter = rowCounter+1` was also necessary in order to keep track of the target row on PLSheet.
- The value of `installation oui/non` is taken from Column F on PROSheet

  - however res does not include a value for this column
  - so it is necessary to return this value from `values`. This requires know the relevant row number on PROSheet which is calculated as i/6 or `values[rowIdx][5]`

---

```
function ejbPLANNING_ques() {
  var PLsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PLANNING_DATA");
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");

  //Clean sheet
  PLsheet.getRange('A2:I').clearContent()

  // planning
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: PRO sheet range = "+PROsheet.getRange('A5:AI' + PROsheet.getLastRow()).getA1Notation())
  var values = PROsheet.getRange('A5:AI' + PROsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var res = values.flatMap(valueRange =>
  {
    var temp = valueRange[19] instanceof Date ? new Date(valueRange[19].getTime() + (7 * 86400000)) : valueRange[19];
  return [
    [valueRange[2], valueRange[1], valueRange[4], valueRange[6], valueRange[18], valueRange[22], 'durée projet', valueRange[9], valueRange[11]],//project lenght
    [valueRange[2], valueRange[1], valueRange[4], valueRange[6], valueRange[18], valueRange[19], 'conception', valueRange[9], valueRange[11]],//research lenght
    [valueRange[2], valueRange[1], valueRange[4], valueRange[6], valueRange[19], temp, 'retour BAT', valueRange[9], valueRange[11]],//waiting for client
    [valueRange[2], valueRange[1], valueRange[4], valueRange[6], temp, valueRange[20], 'mise en fabrication', valueRange[9], valueRange[11]],//mise en production 3D time
    [valueRange[2], valueRange[1], valueRange[4], valueRange[6], valueRange[20], valueRange[21], 'fabrication', valueRange[9], valueRange[11]],//production time
    [valueRange[2], valueRange[1], valueRange[4], valueRange[6], valueRange[21], valueRange[22], 'installation', valueRange[9], valueRange[11]]//installation on site
   ];
  });


  // clean res false true;
  // rowCounter keeps count of the row number in PLSheet
  var rowCounter = 0
  // create a temporary array to hold values
  var tempArray = new Array
  // loop through res arrays-6 arrays per row
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i += 6) {
      if (res[i][0] === true) {
        // get the row number on PROSheet
        if (i==0){var rowIdx = 0}else{var rowIdx = i/6}
        Logger.log("DEBUG: TRUE: i="+i+", valueid="+rowIdx+", target range = "+PLsheet.getRange(2+rowCounter, 1,1,9).getA1Notation()+" value = "+res[i][0]+", row = "+res[i]+" , FINISH:"+res[i][0]+", PROJECT:"+res[i][1]+", DESCRIPTION:"+res[i][2]+", RESPONSIBLE:"+res[i][3]+", START DATE:"+res[i][4]+", END DATE:"+res[i][5]+" , TYPE:"+", not known"+", 3D oui/non:"+res[i][7]+", installation oui/non:"+values[rowIdx][5])
      tempArray.push([res[i][0],res[i][1],res[i][2],res[i][3],res[i][4],res[i][5],"not known",res[i][7],values[rowIdx][5]])
      rowCounter = rowCounter+1
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("DEBUG: FALSE: i="+i+" value = "+res[i][0]+", row = "+res[i]);    
    }

  }
  var rows = tempArray.length
  var plLR = PLsheet.getLastRow()
  PLsheet.getRange(plLR+1, 1, rows , 9).setValues(tempArray)
}
```

---

**RESULTS**

[image: results]